# Why can light from a laser burn things, and from an LED or lamp cannot?

Tags: laser

Considering a focused laser beam of 1000mW power, it will burn paper or wood slightly. 
Focussing the light of an 1000mW LED does not do so. Why is that?
Is it because the laser is monochromatic? What makes the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a better lens.  Seriously, which is to say that the LED is dumping its output power into a large solid angle, so re-collecting it all is rather difficult.

Also, are you certain you're quoting the mean output power of both devices?  If that's their peak power, the LED's mean power could be far less if (as with many LEDs) it's pulsed to reduce the internal heat load.

Comment: I see, so if the two light sources had the same _output_ power and proper focussing it shouldn't make a difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What matters is the power per unit area. The reason the laser can burn is that the laser, being well collimated, can be focused to a much smaller point than the LED. As the power from the LED is spread over a larger area in the source emitter, the optical invariant prevents one from focusing this to a small point while capturing the whole solid angle of emitted power. The original answer is wrong in this regard, there is no lens capable of doing this in such a way as to match the power density of the focused laser.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I’ve just come across this post...
today I was using my aqua illumination LED reef hd light for my marine tank, on doing a water change, I placed the light on to a wooden surface, although the light was on its daily schedule with mainly blue and uv intensity of 65% of its peak power, after ten minutes there was smoke coming from the device I lifted it up and the led’s power had literally burnt and almost set fire to the wooden surface.
As a consumer I really didn’t think this was possible from LEDs and I only thought lasers could do such thing, but I was glad I noticed it when I did otherwise it could have resulted in an house fire [image]